# nutch1.14 deduplication failed

Tags: hadoop, solr, web-crawler, bigdata, nutch

I have integrated `nutch` 1.14 along with `solr-6.6.0` on CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 I had given about 10 urls in seedlist which is at /usr/local/apache-nutch-1.13/urls/seed.txt I followed the [tutorial](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial)

```
[root@localhost apache-nutch-1.14]# bin/nutch dedup http://ip:8983/solr/
DeduplicationJob: starting at 2018-01-09 15:07:52
DeduplicationJob: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: http
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat.listStatus(SequenceFileInputFormat.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeOldSplits(JobSubmitter.java:329)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:196)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1746)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:575)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:570)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1746)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:570)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:561)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:870)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.DeduplicationJob.run(DeduplicationJob.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.DeduplicationJob.main(DeduplicationJob.java:369)
```

Everything upto solr related commands work. Please help.
Where is the hadoop element they are talking about in nutch tutorial. Do we have to install anything other than java for hadoop, nutch and solr to work together to build a search engine?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
bin/nutch dedup -Dsolr.server.url=http://ip:8983/solr/
```

Answer (score 0):

I was reading the same guide and ran into the same problem. This might help:

```
(Step-by-Step: Deleting Duplicates)  
$ bin/nutch dedup crawl/crawldb/ -Dsolr.server.url=http://localhost:8983/solr/nutch

DeduplicationJob: starting at 2018-02-23 14:27:34  
Deduplication: 1 documents marked as duplicates  
Deduplication: Updating status of duplicate urls into crawl db.  
Deduplication finished at 2018-02-23 14:27:37, elapsed: 00:00:03
```